# JavaFX ComboBox binding

Tags: javafx

lets say that I have two models. Teacher and Students and each Student can have one Teacher (not several). So I want to have an combo box on my student pane where I can select one teacher.

Both models are also stored in the database and I want only the database ID of the teacher to be in the model of the student but inside the combo box the name of the teacher should appear.

Also the model should be binded to the combo box, so if somebody changed the teacher in the combobox, the model (of the student) should be refreshed as well. With textfields I can bind them to StringProperty objects, but in this case I need to bind the comboxbox item (Teacher.java) to an interger-property inside my Student.java.

I also thought about having the teacher-model as a property inside my student class, but I think that will not help, because then I need to bind the combobox item (teacher.java) with a teacher object inside my student model but only *property* objects can be binded.

**Teacher.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Teacher {

    private Integer databaseID;

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private IntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty();


    public Teacher (Integer databaseID) {
        // load data from database and fill into model
    }

    public void store() {
        // write model to database
    }

    // getters and setters ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // compare databaseIDs ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Student {

    private Integer databaseID;

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private Integer teacherID;


    public Student (Integer databaseID) {
        // load data from database and fill into model
    }

    public void store() {
        // write model to database
    }

    // getters and setters ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // compare databaseIDs ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Student student = new Student(4711);

        ComboBox<Teacher> teachers = new ComboBox<Teacher>();
        fillTeacherComboBox(teachers);

        // TODO: select the teacher from the student by default

        // FIXME: Binding student.databaseID <--> ComboBox-Item.databaseID


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(teachers);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void fillTeacherComboBox(ComboBox<Teacher> teachers) {
        // TODO: Load data from database and fill teacher combo box
    }


}
```

Comment: *"I want only the database ID of the teacher to be in the model of the student"*. Why would you want that? Why not just have a reference to the teacher in the model of the student?

Comment: Does that fix the problem? *I also thought about having the teacher-model as a property inside my student class, but I think that will not help, because then I need to bind the combobox item (teacher.java) with a teacher object inside my student model but only property objects can be binded.*

Comment: Well it makes it easier. Surely the fix for "only property objects can be bound" is to use JavaFX properties in your `Student` and `Teacher` classes?

Comment: Well it seems that this is not really possible. Other people did this by using a changelistener and set the selected teacher model to the student model inside the changelistener. That is not really nice but it works.

Maybe somebody else has a better idea?

Comment: Why isn't that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would make (at least) one change to the design here: store a reference to the `Teacher` object in the `Student` object (and use a JavaFX property to do it):

```
public class Student {

    private Integer databaseID;

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private ObjectProperty<Teacher> teacher = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();


    public Student (Integer databaseID) {
        // load data from database and fill into model

        /* Just as an aside, it is really bad practice to include
           database code in your domain objects as you suggest here.
           You should create a separate class that manages the database
           code (a DataAccessObject) and the domain objects Student and 
           Teacher should be completely agnostic as to the mechanism by
           which they are persisted (or even whether they are persisted).*/
    }

    public void store() {
        // write model to database

        // see above comment.
    }

    // getters and setters ...

    public ObjectProperty<Teacher> teacherProperty() {
        return teacher ;
    }

    public final Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacherProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        teacherProperty().set(teacher);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // compare databaseIDs ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

And now you just do

```
Student student = ... ;
ComboBox<Teacher> teachers = new ComboBox<>();
// populate combo box...
teachers.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(student.teacherProperty());
```

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that it implies tremendous code duplication - for every data model I now have to have to classes - one for DB/persistence and one for UI. Unless I misunderstood your remark in `Student`'s constructor.

Comment: Yes, I think you misunderstood that comment. The DAO only manages the persistence (saving and loading to/from the database) of the entities. The entities are not duplicated (neither is the persistence code).

Comment: Ah, I see. So you have one model class, which has Observables and JavaFX properties, and the DAO saves and loads this to and from the persistence layer? I presume this means there are no significant downsides to having JavaFX-properties on classes that are used outside UI scope?

Comment: Some might consider the additional API dependence a downside, but imo it is not an issue. If you are sharing the same database with a non-FX application, then you can either use your FX-based entities in the non-FX application, or create a parallel set of entities (code duplication). If you don't use JavaFX properties in your entities, then you can't do binding as the OP points out. So imo the API dependence on JavaFX properties is the lesser evil.

Comment: That is a good solution and the database issue I will think about. I know it is not so good to mix database and model structures, but my first attempt was to write converter between model and database objects in both directions. But in order to get everything to work, I put it directly into the model. I think that can be changed really quick afterwards. But thanks for the ObjectProperty solution. I didn't know that property!

Comment: I implemented this and I really appreciate it! I am having issues with the initial selected item though. When I look at the combobox, the item is in the label, but when I double click it, the item is not automatically selected as though it is when I was doing this with just a string. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You Can try one of these:(worked for me)

```
semesterBoxDay.selectionModelProperty().bind(semesterBox.selectionModelProperty());
```

When change 1st one 2d one change and verse happen,I know this is odd i don't know if there's explain for that (it work like bindBidirectional() here)

```
semesterBoxDay.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(semesterBox.valueProperty());
```

when i use bind() here i can't change the 2d one value until i change the 1st one

(i think because the 2d one value will never change untill u set it but i don't know why not change if click the new item in list). if anyone have answer for these problems i hope he could write them .

Comment: "When change 1st one 2d one change and verse happen" -- what does this mean?