# Binding between an Object and a SimpleIntegerProperty

Tags: binding, javafx-2

I have a combo box over my GUI in JavaFX.
This Combo Box is composed of a complex type elements :

```
public class DureeChoiceBoxElement extends ObservableValueBase<DureeChoiceBoxElement> {

    private IntegerProperty duree;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return duree.get() + " an";
    }
}
```

I want to map (or bind) the selected complex element with my model which contains the simple type :

```
public class Pel {
private IntegerProperty duree = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

public Property<Number> dureeProperty() {
        return duree;
    }

public void setDuree(Integer duree) {
        this.duree.setValue(duree);
    }

public Integer getDuree() {
        return duree.getValue();
    }

}
```

How to do it ?

I tried in the controller with :

```
    public class PelController {

    @FXML
        private ChoiceBox<DureeChoiceBoxElement> duree;
//etc..
        pel.dureeProperty().bind(createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI2(duree.getValue()));

        /*
             * @return an ObjectBinding of immutable TimeElapsed objects for the player
             */
            private ObjectBinding<Property<Number>> createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI2(
                    final DureeChoiceBoxElement dureeChoiceBoxElement) {

                return Bindings.createObjectBinding(new Callable<Property<Number>>() {
                    @Override
                    public IntegerProperty call() throws Exception {
                        return dureeChoiceBoxElement.dureeProperty();
                    }
                }, dureeChoiceBoxElement.dureeProperty());
            }
    }
```

But it doesn't work (even not compile). I want to say that "Bind this simple property to this complex Object calling the method I give you through the method named "createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI2(..)".
It is logical read but I didn't managed to make it works anyway.
That's poor ....
Any help please :).

Comment: Related question (with different solution approach, but may be of help): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506662/javafx-combobox-binding

Comment: Someone suggested to code manually the binding implementing a change listener. I counted on the power of JavaFX with high level binding. Less code would be better !

Answer (score 0):

Example that (obviously) works with legacy code style (Swing coding) :

```
duree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<DureeChoiceBoxElement>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends DureeChoiceBoxElement> observable,
                    DureeChoiceBoxElement oldValue, DureeChoiceBoxElement newValue) {
                // changement durée
                log.debug("Durée sélectionnée : {}", duree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getDuree());
                log.debug("Durée bindée ? : {}", pel.getDuree());
                pel.setDuree(duree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getDuree());

            }
        });
```

Like this my model is set to selected item. But it implies some boilerplate code. Any better idea based on high level bindings of JavaFX ?

Comment: But on the other way, the high level binding works (from model->combo box) : duree.valueProperty()
    .bind(createElapsedBindingByBindingsAPI(new DureeChoiceBoxElement(pel.getDuree().intValue())));